# Usage of Restock

Tags: grammar, word-usage

In this [News transcript](http://www.npr.org/templates/transcript/transcript.php?storyId=336905809)

> The goal is to hit pause on the fighting long enough to allow civilians in Gaza to take care of injured people, bury the dead and **restock on** food and other supplies.

But I found many sentences online that there are no **on**.

> Companies that have depleted their inventories will restock them.
>
> Work began at once to restock the fishery.

So how to use restock? With or without on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a matter of using "restock" as an intransitive verb, rather than as a transitive verb.

To "restock on (X)" means to "refill one's own stock of (X)". In this case, it means that the civilians are going to restock their own supplies, as opposed to placing materials on someone else's shelves.